# NancyFx Authentication per Route

Tags: authentication, routes, nancy

From what I saw in the source code RequiresAuthentication() does an Authentication check for the whole module. Is there any way to do this per Route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace Kallist.Modules {

    #region Namespaces

    using System;
    using Nancy;

    #endregion

    public static class ModuleExtensions {

        #region Methods

        public static Response WithAuthentication(this NancyModule module, Func<Response> executeAuthenticated) {
            if ((module.Context.CurrentUser != null) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(module.Context.CurrentUser.UserName)) {
                return executeAuthenticated();
            }
            return new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. However it turns out the `RequiresAuthentication` works at both the module level and the route level. To demonstrate, here is some code ripped out my current project (not all routes shown for brevity).

```
public class RegisterModule : _BaseModule
{
    public RegisterModule() : base("/register")
    {
        Get["/basic-details"] = _ => View["RegisterBasicDetailsView", Model];

        Get["/select"] = _ =>
            {
                this.RequiresAuthentication();
                return View["RegisterSelectView", Model];
            };
    }
}
```

Of course the only problem with doing it this way is that all the protected routes in the module need to call `RequiresAuthentication`. In the case of my module above, I have another 5 routes (not shown) all of which need protecting, so that makes six calls to `RequiresAuthentication` instead of one at the module level. The alternative would be to pull the unprotected route into another module, but my judgement was that a proliferation of modules is worse than the additional RequiresAuthentication calls.

Comment: I didn't try to call RequiresAuthentication from route because didn't seem to work after a look on the source code. I have created a new extension method that does the same checks on context.CurrentUser but returns bool.

Comment: I have posted the code below and you can use it like this.WithAuthentication(() => { /* Code that requires an authenticated user */ });

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, here's how I solved it.

```
        var module = new MyModule();
        module.AddBeforeHookOrExecute(context => null, "Requires Authentication");
        _browser = new Browser(with =>
            {
                with.Module(module);
                with.RequestStartup((container, pipelines, ctx) =>
                    {
                        ctx.CurrentUser = new User { UserId = "1234", UserName = "test"};
                    });
            });
```

I can now use this.RequiresAuthentication() at the module level and run my unit tests.