# Can a web service provide NTLM authentication against a domain without being a domain member?

Tags: authentication, owin, ntlm, nancy

Can a web service provide NTLM authentication against a domain without being a domain member?

What I have is a simple Nancy web service that is self-hosted via Owin to support NTLM authentication (inspired by a [gist from Damian Hickey](https://gist.github.com/damianh/10086352), [slightly modified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164276/1811525)). This works very well as long as the service runs on a machine that has joined the relevant domain.

Now I am looking for a way to authenticate the client via NTLM when the service is running on a machine which is **not a member** of any Windows domain (which I think is what is called *pass-through authentication* in this [SSPI tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973911.aspx)).

After reading many articles regarding NTLM and SSPI, I am still not sure if this scenario is possible at all.